# React Native function

Tags: javascript, wordpress, react-native, function

I am trying to create a simple function which can be called in a React Native Screen, which returns an array with data.

I am importing the function here:

```
import React from 'react'
...
import { getvals } from '../components/Data_funks';

export default function ProjectsScreen({ route, navigation }) {

      const { data }    = route.params;
      const mail        = data.item.kontakte_mail;

    // this is how I call the function:
    getvals(data.item.projekt_bauleiter).then(response => console.log(response));
```

The array is displayed in the console but I cannot access the data of it. This is the function:

```
import React from 'react'
import { Image, StyleSheet } from 'react-native'
import clientConfig from '../../client-config';


export function getvals(user_id){
          const siteUrl = clientConfig.siteUrl + '/wp-json/zep/v1/' + user_id;
    return fetch(siteUrl,
    {
        method: "GET",
        headers: {
             Authorization: 'Bearer '+localStorage.getItem( 'token' )
        },
    })
    .then((response) => response.json())
    
    .then((responseData) => {
        
    const error = responseData.data.error_code; 

        
    if(error == 0){     
        
      return responseData;
        
    }else{
        
        return 'error';
    }
        
        
    })
    .catch(error => console.warn(error));
  }
```

Comment: "The array is displayed in the console but I cannot access the data of it." — Well, you clearly *can* access the data since it is your code that is passing it to `console.log`. You don't appear to have any other code trying to access it. What's the problem?

Comment: That is the problem, I don´t know how to access the data :(

Comment: `then(response => console.log(response));` <-- like that

Comment: I dont mean showing it in the console. How can I display the data in this response Object in a View? For example here: `<View style={{paddingTop:10,}}>
  { data.item.projekt_name !='Kein Titel'? <Text style={styles.HeadNameStyle}>{data.item.projekt_name} 
  <Text>{"\n"}</Text>
  {data.item.projekt_nummer}</Text> : <Text style={styles.HeadNameStyle}>{data.item.projekt_nummer}</Text> }
        </View>'

Answer (score 0):

You could save the `response` data in a `state`.

```js
export default function ProjectsScreen({ route, navigation }) {

      const { data }    = route.params;
      const mail        = data.item.kontakte_mail;
      const [response, setResponse] = useState()

      useEffect(() => {
          const init = async () => {
              const response = await getvals(data.item.projekt_bauleiter)
              setResponse(response)
          }   
          init()
      }, [route.params])

      console.log(response)

...
}
```

Answer (score -1):

I dont know if this is a typo.. but it seems that you log the string 'response'

```
getvals(data.item.projekt_bauleiter).then(response => console.log('response'));
```

Comment: Hi PlaeschZ, no that was just a test.